# 'sum' not meaningful for factors while using diag(prop.table()) functionality

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn

I'm trying to find the mean of misclassification count upon running of KNN algorithm which generated a confusion matrix. Below is the result when i execute "prop.table(t,1)"

```
kdd_train <- dataset_normalized[1:140000,]
kdd_test <- dataset_normalized[140001:145586,]

kdd_train_target <- dataset_extracted[1:140000,12]
kdd_test_target <- dataset_extracted[140001:145586,12]
prop.table(t,1)
               m1
kdd_test_target       FALSE        TRUE
          FALSE 0.997044917 0.002955083
          TRUE  0.048592189 0.951407811
```

However when i execute the command "error_per_class = diag(prop.table(m1))", it returned an error

```
> error_per_class = diag(prop.table(m1))
Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

Is there any way to fix it ? Appreciate any help thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is mentioned in the `error`, the `variable` is `factor`.  It is not possible to apply `prop.table` directly on a `factor` class as it requires some computation.

```
prop.table(m1)
```

> Error in Summary.factor(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>   :    ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

Based on the values shown, it should be a logical vector, so convert it to logical and it should work

```
as.logical(m1)
prop.table(as.logical(m1))
#[1] 0.09090909 0.09090909 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.09090909 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.09090909 0.00000000 0.09090909 0.00000000 0.00000000
#[15] 0.09090909 0.00000000 0.09090909 0.09090909 0.00000000 0.09090909 0.09090909 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.09090909
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
m1 <- factor(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 24, replace=TRUE))
kdd_test_target  <- factor(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 24, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: hi akrun, thanks for the reply. the m1 table was generated after train and test target. i have edited the code to reflect the flow. So where should i add the changes you recommend?

Comment: @misctpasdas  Looks like you are usnig it on the 12th column, so, do this on that column, i.e. `as.logical(kdd_test_target)`.  Regarding the `m1`, it is not shown in the example you posted